# Jekyll: issues with menu links when deploying on github pages

Tags: ruby, jekyll

I've deployed a [Jekyll blog](http://marv.ink) using Github pages, but there appears to be an issue when it generates links for different menu pages.

Here's my _config.yml site settings.

```
# Site settings
title: Marvin K
description: "Now Loading"
baseurl: " " 
url: "marv.ink" 


# Build settings
markdown: kramdown
highlighter: rouge
permalink: /:title/

# html minify
compress_html:
  clippings: all
  comments: all
  endings: []
  profile: false

# Links to include in menu navigation
links:
  section_1:
    - title: home
      url: /
      key_trigger: 1
    - title: my posts
      url: /posts
      key_trigger: 2
    - title: series
      url: /series
      key_trigger: 3
    - title: tags
      url: /tags
      key_trigger: 4
    - title: about me
      url: /about
      key_trigger: 5

# projects in header index
projects:


# exclude my node related stuff
exclude: ['package.json', 'src', 'node_modules']
```

Any help figuring this out would be great

Thanks

Comment: Try to remove the `/` at the end of `url`.

Comment: Please post the content of _config.yml into the question so we don't take the risk of link going down or changing the content.

Comment: @DanieleCappuccio it fixed the formatting but menu links are still not working correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make your menu work on github pages you can :

In ***_config.yml*** :

```
baseurl: "/blog"

...

links:
  section_1:
    - title: home
      url: /
      key_trigger: 1
    - title: my posts
      url: /posts
      key_trigger: 2
...
```

In ***_includes/menu-search.html***, change

```
<a key-trigger={{ link.key_trigger }}
   href="{{ site.url }}{{ link.url }}"> {{ link.title }}</a>
```

to read :

```
<a key-trigger={{ link.key_trigger }}
   href="{{ site.baseurl }}{{ link.url }}"> {{ link.title }}</a>
```

This is based on what I saw [here](https://github.com/marvinkhywah/blog).

Comment: I ending up leaving the baseurl blank.
Thanks that did it!